# Why is log base 10 used in this code to convert int to string?

Tags: c, string, int

I saw a post explaining how to convert an int to a string. In the explanation there is a line of code to get the number of chars in a string:

```
(int)((ceil(log10(num))+1)*sizeof(char))
```

I’m wondering why log base 10 is used?

Comment: Note: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so the `* sizeof(char)` is useless.

Comment: Better to just use, e.g. `float num = 292.818; int needed = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%.2f", num) + 1;` You can specify whatever output format you like and `snprintf (NULL, 0, ...` will tell you the number of characters that would be required to store the format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`ceil(log10(num))+1` is incorrectly being used instead of `floor(log10(num))+2`**.

The code is attempting to determine the amount of memory needed to store the decimal representation of the positive integer `num` as a string.

The two formulas presented above are equal except for numbers which are exact powers of 10, in which case the former version returns one less than the desired number.

For example, 10,000 requires 6 bytes, yet `ceil(log10(10000))+1` returns `5`. `floor(log10(10000))+2` correctly returns 6.

Zero and negative integers need to be handled differently.

---

**How was `floor(log10(num))+2` obtained?**

A 4-digit positive integer such as 4567 will be between 1,000 (inclusive) and 10,000 (exclusive), so it will be between 10<sup>3</sup> (inclusive) and 10<sup>4</sup> (exclusive), so its log<sub>10</sub> will be between 3 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive).

As such, `floor(log10(num))+1` will return number of digits needed to represent the positive value `num` in decimal.

As such, `floor(log10(num))+2` will return the amount of memory needed to store the decimal representation of the positive integer `num` as a string. (The extra char is for the NUL that terminates the string.)

Comment: Not if the number is a power of 10.

Comment: @BessieTheCow, Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

> I’m wondering why log base 10 is used?

I'm wondering the same thing. It uses a *very* complex calculation that happens at runtime, to save a couple bytes of *temporary* storage. And it does it wrong.

---

In principle, you get the number of digits in base 10 by taking the base-10 logarithm and *flooring* and adding 1. It comes exactly from the fact that

```
log10(1) = log10(10⁰) = 0
log10(10) = log10(10¹) = 1
log10(100) = log10(10²) = 2
```

and all numbers between 10 and 100 have their logarithms between 1 and 2 so if you floor the logarithm for any two digit number you get 1... add 1 and you get the number of digits.

But you do not need to do this at runtime. The maximum number of bytes needed for a 32-bit int in base 10 is 10 digits, negative sign and null terminator for 12 chars. The maximum you can save with the runtime calculation are 10 *bytes* of RAM, but it is usually temporary so it is not worth it. If it is stack memory, well, the call to `log10`, `ceil` and so forth might require far more.

---

In fact, we know the maximum number of *bits* needed to represent an integer: `sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT`. This is greater than or equal to *log2* of the `MAX_INT + 1`. And we know that `log10(x)` =~ `3.32192809489 * log2(x)`, so we get a good (possibly floored) approximation of `log10(MAX_INT)` by just dividing `sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT` by 3. Then add `1` for *we were supposed to add 1 to the floored logarithm to get the number of digits*, then `1` for possible sign, and `1` for the null terminator and we get

```
sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 3
```

Unlike the one from your question, this is an *integer constant expression*, i.e. the compiler can easily fold it at the compilation time, and it can be used to set the size of a statically-typed array, and for 32-bits it gives **13** which is only one more than the 12 actually required, for 16 bits it gives **8** which is again only one more than the maximum required 7 and for 8 bits it gives **5** which is the exact maximum.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ceil(log10(num)) + 1 is intended to provide the number of characters needed for the output string.

For example, if num=101, the expression's value is 4, the correct length of '101' plus the null terminator.

But if num=100, the value is 3. This behavior is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's allocating enough space for the number to fit in the string.

If, for example, you had the number 1034, `log10(1034) = 3.0145...`. `ceil(3.0145)` is 4, which is the number of digits in the number. The `+ 1` is for the null-terminator.

This isn't perfect though: take 1000, for example. Despite having four digits, `log(1000) = 3`, and `ceil(3) = 3`, so this will allocate space for too few digits. Plus, as @phuclv mentions below, the `log()` function is very time-consuming for this purpose, especially since the length of a number has a (relatively low) upper-bound.

The reason it's log base 10 is because, presumably, this function represents the number in decimal form. If, for example, it were hexadecimal, log base 16 would be used.

Comment: it's completely unnecessary and makes that converting algorithm much slower. You already know the longest int value (which is 11 characters for 32-bit int) so just allocate a 12-byte array, convert the digits then reverse

Answer (score 0):

A number `N` has n decimal digits iff `10^(n-1) <= N < 10^n` which is equivalent to `n-1 <= log(N) < n` or `n = floor(log(N)) + 1`.

Since `double` representation has only limited precision `floor(log(N))` may be off by 1 for certain values, so it is safer to allow for an extra digit i.e. allocate `floor(log(N)) + 2` characters, and then another char for the nul terminator for a total of of `floor(log(N)) + 3`.

The expression in the original question `ceil(log(N)) + 1` appears to not count the nul terminator, and neither allow for the chance of rounding errors, so it is one shorter in general, and two shorter for powers of 10.